# how to use ECDSA to create a self signed digital certificate programatically

Tags: openssl, digital-signature, pki, ecdsa

I am trying to create a digital certificate which to be self signed with EC keys instead of those from RSA and followed these SO [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256405/programmatically-create-x509-certificate-using-openssl) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228860/signing-a-message-using-ecdsa-in-openssl). I replaced the signature algorithm from RSA given in link1 to EC as

```
EC_KEY *ecc = NULL;
int eccgrp = OBJ_txt2nid("secp256k1");
ecc = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(eccgrp);
EC_KEY_set_asn1_flag(ecc, OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE);

if(!(EC_KEY_generate_key(ecc))) {
    BIO_printf(out, "Error in generating key");
    printf("Error 1\n");
}

if(!EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(pk, ecc)) {
    BIO_printf(out, "Error assigning EC_KEY to EVP_PKEY");
    printf("Error 2\n");
}
.
.
X509_set_pubkey(x,pk);
.
.
if (!X509_sign(x,pk,EVP_md5()))
    goto err;
.
.
```

Rest of the code is same as given in link1. No error is printed but i get a seg-fault when i try to print the x509 cert `X509_print_fp(stdout,x509);`. What is correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You changed [that code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256405/programmatically-create-x509-certificate-using-openssl) more than you said because it doesn't have variables 'pk' or 'x'.

Anytime you get an error/failure return from a libcrypto routine you should always look at the error queue; see https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG6 and https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG7 . (For libssl routines you should do so depending on the return from [SSL_get_error](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_get_error.html).) If you do so as in my code below for the 'bad' case, you see `X509_sign` fails with

```
140018941793960:error:100C508A:elliptic curve routines:PKEY_EC_CTRL:invalid digest type:ec_pmeth.c:388:
```

because standard ECDSA signature schemes don't include MD5. **You must use SHA1 or SHA2**, and you *should* use a hash matched in strength to the ECC key, which in this case is SHA256. Since the signature failed, the `x509` structure does not contain valid data and can't be successfully printed.

Also note: since 1.0.0 (in 2010) `PEM_write_PrivateKey` with `enc` nonnull uses 'new' (ca. 2000!) PKCS#8/PBES2 format, which needs a suitable variant of `OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms`.

**Complete working demo-quality code:**

```
/* SO #35899969 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <openssl/applink.c>
#endif

/* minimal error handling for demo; real code do better */
void err (const char *label)
{
  fprintf (stderr, "Error in %s:\n", label);
  ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);
  exit (1);
}

int main (int argc, char**argv)
{
  int bad = argc>1;
  ERR_load_crypto_strings(); /* or SSL_load_error_strings */
  OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf(); /* for PKCS8 w PBES2 */

  EVP_PKEY * pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
  EC_KEY *ecc = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
  /* simpler than going through OBJ_txt2nid */
  if(!ecc) err("ECCnewbyname");
  EC_KEY_set_asn1_flag(ecc, OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE);
  if(!(EC_KEY_generate_key(ecc))) err("ECCgen");
  if(!EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(pkey, ecc)) err("PKEYassign");

  X509 * x509 = X509_new();
  /* REALLY shouldn't use fixed serial if DN isn't unique */
  ASN1_INTEGER_set(X509_get_serialNumber(x509), 1);
  X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(x509), 0);
  X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(x509), 365L*86400);
  X509_set_pubkey(x509, pkey);
  X509_NAME * name = X509_get_subject_name(x509);
  X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name, "C",  MBSTRING_ASC,
                           (unsigned char *)"CA", -1, -1, 0);
  X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name, "O",  MBSTRING_ASC,
                           (unsigned char *)"MyCompany Inc.", -1, -1, 0);
  X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name, "CN", MBSTRING_ASC,
                           (unsigned char *)"localhost", -1, -1, 0);
  X509_set_issuer_name(x509, name);
  if(!X509_sign(x509, pkey, bad? EVP_md5(): EVP_sha256())) err("X509sign");

  /* simplified */
  if(!PEM_write_PrivateKey(stdout, pkey, EVP_des_ede3_cbc(),
                          NULL,0,NULL,"passphrase")) 
    err("writeKey");
  if(!PEM_write_X509(stdout, x509))
    err("writeCert");
  /* added */
  X509_print_fp (stdout, x509); 
  return 0;
}
```